# Why does lithium have a total electronic spin of 1/2?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, physical-chemistry, atoms

The book I'm reading analyses atoms by only looking at the last eletrons, and saying that their wave function must be anti-symmetric.

I understand the  case of Helium, the spin function must be anti symmetric, so total S = 0 (singlet), but when we add another eletron, there is no reason why we must keep the last two in the same state S = 0, so the new eletron will add a 1/2 to total spin. Don't the addition of a new eletron add a possibility of having like the first two eletrons with same spin?

I can see that this way of calculating total spin is followed in bigger atoms, how to justify this? Like in Be, if we analyse only the last two eletrons, ignoring that there is two more, the spatial wave function will have to be symmetric, so again S = 0 (singlet). Why we can do this? Is it because the eletrons in a new shell are so far apart that we only need to care about the symmetry of the pair in the same spatial state?

Comment: Perhaps you should study Pauli exclusion, the Aufbau principle and Hund's rules. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle.

Comment: But even if we assume these rules to be true, why two spins up and one down ( or two down and one up) will only giv total spin 1/2, Ideally we should look to the expansion of the total state of the combination of three spins 1/2, but no book does it.